# CKAN permission denied in apache2.4.7 datapusher

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, ckan

I followed this instruction in setting up the datapusher in ckan http://docs.ckan.org/projects/datapusher/en/latest/

The datastore works fine. I can save it and can preview the resources. The problem is when I upload the resource It gives me an error saying "You don't have permission to access job on this server."

The content of my port.conf:

```
Listen 80

<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
NameVirtualHost *:8800
Listen 8800
```

Every time I start the apache server it says:

AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release /etc/apache2/ports.conf:16

Anyone can help me with this?.. I am new in ubuntu.

Comment: The log says "Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /etc/ckan" ..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your /usr/lib/ckan or /etc/ckan is a symblink. There is a part of the instructions which recommends installing CKAN to your home folder for development. Did you accidentally follow that step?